# Looking for library for reading iPod's database

Tags: python, database, perl, ipod

I'm looking for a library that will let me to examine and modify my iPod's internal database(s) programmatically.

My primary goal is to delete some seriously space-hogging files that, for reasons too complicated to go into, the iTunes interface is not letting me delete.

Hence it is critical for me to determine the actual file paths associated with individual entries in my iPod.  (iTunes obfuscates these paths to hide their contents.  They match the Perl regex `m,^.*/iPod_Control/Music/F\d\d/[A-Z]{4}.[a-zA-Z]+$,`.)

As a secondary goal, I would like to modify my iPod's internal bookkeeping so that these deletions are properly recorded.

In case it matters, I need to do this from OS X.

I'd much prefer a Python library for this, but if no such library exists, a Perl library will do too.

Thanks!

P.S. At first I tried to do this task with some suitable 3rd party app, but none of the ones I checked out inspired in me any confidence of leaving my iPod in a sane/uncorrupted state.  Hence I decided to write a script to do this.

P.S. 2: The files I want to delete are not shown in the xml file that iTunes generates when one runs the export command.  (The files are definitely in my iPod, though, since I can play them.)  Therefore, any solution based on this xml file is out.

P.S. 3: None of the files I need to delete is mp3, or even audio, so any mp3-oriented or audio-file-oriented solution is out.

Comment: This probably sounds a bit lame, but have you thought about just wiping the iPod and restoring your music/videos from iTunes? A little like the typical Windows user approach. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

libgpod http://www.gtkpod.org/wiki/Libgpod has Python bindings.